# Help Center for Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, area-51, help-center

Is area 51 going to have the help center? The content would be different, but I like the idea of the help center and I think we should be consistent across all of the sites.

Comment: Probably not. Their efforts are most likely directed at the replacement to Area 51.

Comment: @animuson The area 52?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have no plans for adding the help center to Area 51 in the near future. Area 51 is pretty separate from the rest of the network, so you're right; it would need completely different content. Besides that, we are still looking at making changes to the way Area 51 works, so it makes more sense to hold off on writing any new help/faq copy until we finalize our plans for those changes.